# "I have a friend VISITING me." Participle vs entire Direct Object Clause

Tags: parts-of-speech, participles, direct-objects, adjectival-phrases

"I have a friend *visiting* me." Which part of speech is "visiting" specifically?

Even if "a friend visiting me" is an entire **direct object clause**, what is the breakdown:

- Is "visiting" a **participle**?
- Is "me" a **direct object** of visiting (since friend, the original direct object, is engaging in a transitive verb)?
- Or is "visiting me" an **adjectival phrase**? (i.e. "a friend *[who is] visiting me*")

Additionally.. "I have a friend visiting."

- Is "visiting" still the same as above, but simply omitting the presumptive *me*? Or does this change anything?

I understand that "I have a *visiting* friend." would involve a clear participle.

Edit: I have a friend *visiting*. (The word "visiting" is a **participle**. Which though not a part of speech per se, functions as an adjective.)

I have a friend *visiting me*. (The words "visiting me" form a **participial phrase**. Very similar to an adjectival phrase in the sense that it functions as an adjective and modifies *friend*. The word "me" would indeed be a **direct object** nested in the participial phrase.)

Comment: Because *visiting me* has an object, that tells you that *visiting* is there a verb.

“Participle” is not a part of speech.

Comment: The second part of tchrist's comment is fine; "participle" is not considered a part of speech. As for the first part of that comment, it seems to me that one could equally well say "because "visiting" modifies the noun "friend", that tells you that "visiting" here is an adjective." I'm inclined to use the name "participle" for such words that act as verbs in some respects (e.g., taking direct objects) and like adjectives in other respects (like modifying nouns).

Comment: If you split that into "I have a friend. She is visiting me" does it become more clear?

Comment: "Participle" is too considered a part of speech. As Donatus puts it: _**partes orationis quot sunt?** octo. **quae**? nomen pronomen uerbum aduerbium participium coniunctio praepositio interiectio._

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Thanks! I always forget the KISS principle..